# Node version doesn't change after attempted upgrade in Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

In my Ubuntu machine, I am attempting to update my version of Node. I run `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -`

then I run `sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`

After this, my version of node remains unchanged:

```
ubuntu:~$ node -v 
v6.10.3
```

Comment: well `sudo ap-get upgrade` would be the command you're looking for

Comment: Also a common reason why an upgrade fails to change the version you're running is that you have more than one version of node in your path and the one you're upgrading isn't the one that gets found first in the path.

Answer (score 2):

use nvm, a version manager for node

https://github.com/creationix/nvm

To download node you install nvm and type `nvm install <version>`

This will download both node and npm

To change which node version you want to use you type `nvm use <version>`

For more detail check out the repo ^^

Answer (score 1):

Running this worked for me finally.

Uninstall:

```
sudo apt-get purge nodejs
sudo apt-get autoremove
nvm deactivate
nvm uninstall node_version
```

([Source](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-16-04))

Install the New Version:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
```

If there are errors here, run these 2:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv EA312927

wget -qO - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yarnpkg/releases/gh-pages/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

Install New Version of Node:

```
wget -qO - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yarnpkg/releases/gh-pages/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```